# Infix to postfix with real numbers (included negative ones)

Tags: java

I made an app that allows the transformation from infix to postfix expressions for real numbers (included negative ones). It works perfectly except for the case when I put a negative number on the first and then I put minus another number. For example `-1 - 2` or `-2 + 8 - 9`. It shows `-1-2` and `-2 8-9 +`. It should be `-1 2 -` and `-2 8 + 9 -`. It's certainly a problem when the sign is `-`. This is a part of my code when the input char is '-'.

```
for (int j = 0; j < input.length(); j++) {
    char ch = input.charAt(j);
    if (ch == '-') {
                    if ((ch == input.charAt(0)) || (input.charAt(j - 1) == '(')
                            || (input.charAt(j - 1) == '-'))
                        temp = temp + ch;
                    else {
                        output = output + temp + " ";
                        temp = "";
                        gotOper(ch, 1);
                    }
                }
    else if ..
    ...
    }
```

When the app find `-` and it's on the first of the `input` or after `(` or after `-` so it's a negative number and I put it into a temporary variable. When it's between 0 and 9 or it's `.`, the same thing. else, when it's and operand, I put which is in `temp` in `output` and I do operations with the Stack. I can't show the whole code, it's very long! Can someone help me please?

EDIT: I did this `input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` to remove all whitespaces

Comment: Do you mean that it converts infix to postfix?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I didn't have a good night haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This part `(ch == input.charAt(0))` in the second if-statement should be replaced with `(j == 0)`. Otherwise, it will return true whenever `ch == '-'` if the input also starts with a `'-'`.